# Can I print the final assembled gcc command with premake?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, compilation, premake

I have a premake compilation script. This script generates a make file which can then be used to compile the final exectuable.

I want to instruct premake to instruct the make file to display the final gcc/g++ command

e.g g++ main.cpp -l LIBRARY

Is this possible?

Comment: That's it, thank you

Comment: I guess, considering it's answered the question, I should post it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming gnu make, you'd normally run `make -n`. If you prefer, you can use `make --dry-run` or `make --print-only`.